# QR Code Reader and Generator Application for Android

Tags: java, android, barcode, qr-code, zxing

Newbie here, I already tried using `zxing` library for creating an android app that can generate a QR code image and save it on the phones SD card, a QR code scanner and be able to scan QR code image on my SD.

I have zero programming knowledge in Using Android Developer tools, but I have background in Java programming, I just need a working sample for decoding and encoding...

I already tried  [Decoder Handler](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHandler.java) for decoding an image but I am lost to where to put it on the ADT app.

Same goes for the encoder handler...
I am having a tough time understanding the instructions on the Google Developers website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to start developping in android, you have to learn some basic thinks: How Android works, how to developp correctly etc. To start, I suggest you to use http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

You can also read this tutorial which explains android basis. Once you understood how android works, it will be much easier to understand the Decoder Handler.

If you need more help then, start a new qustion with more precision about errors you are getting or understanding of the code.